# What is the best way to download file using SPLongOperation?

Tags: 2010, splongoperation

I have to build report using SPLongOperation to avoid timeout exception. It doesn't work when I try to push file to response:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = true;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Report.xls");
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

How can i do that?

Comment: At what point you are getting Time out exception?

Comment: Report building can take a long time because of processing big lists

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint requests would timeout after 6 minutes and these executionTimeout settings are set in the web.config file located at the \Template\Layouts directory.

```
<system.web>
    <compilation batch="false" batchTimeout="600" maxBatchSize="10000" maxBatchGeneratedFileSize="10000" />
    <customErrors mode="On" />
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="360" />
    <globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" />
</system.web>
```

If you need to run a really long procedure (e.g., lasting for 1 hour) you need to use other ways, timer jobs, for instance

Also you can try : IIS -> Application Pool -> Advanced Settings -> Process Model -> Shutdown Time Limit (seconds)